# How do I select the nearest `evil-text-object` enclosed in one of () [] {} <> without having to provide the paren char explicitly

Tags: evil, evil-text-object

I have problems when using the suggestion from here [Code faster by extending Emacs EVIL text object](http://blog.binchen.org/posts/code-faster-by-extending-emacs-evil-text-object/)

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(defun jds~evil-paren-range (count beg end type inclusive)
  (->> '((?\( . ?\))
           (?\[ . ?\])
           (?{ . ?})
           (?< . ?>))
         (--keep (save-excursion
                     (ignore-errors
                       (evil-select-paren (car it) (cdr it)
                                        beg end type
                                        count inclusive)) ))
         (-min-by (-on #'> (lambda (x)
                             (abs (- (car x) (point) )))))
         (-take 2)))

(evil-define-text-object jds~evil-a-paren (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select a paren."
  :extend-selection nil 
  (jds~evil-paren-range count beg end type t))

(evil-define-text-object jds~evil-inner-paren (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select inner paren."
    :extend-selection nil
        (jds~evil-paren-range count beg end type nil))

(define-key evil-inner-text-objects-map "d" #'jds~evil-inner-paren)
(define-key evil-outer-text-objects-map "d" #'jds~evil-a-paren)
```

This works great for visually selecting various delimiters in a dwim fasion but for some reason it doesnt work well for deleting, yanking or changing. Here is an example:

Say the point (indicated by `|`) is on a line as follows

```
    |{asdf}(bar)
```

`vad` works exactly as expected and visually selects `{asdf}`.

Yet with the point at same place, `dad` deletes `(bar)` leaving

```
    {asdf}|
```

What is going on? How do I fix this text object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `evil`; I am barely 3 days in to switching to `evil`.  So, I am responding to this question as part of my `evil` learning process.

Try this

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(defun jds~evil-paren-range (count beg end type inclusive)
  (->> '((?\( . ?\))
           (?\[ . ?\])
           (?{ . ?})
           (?< . ?>))
         (--keep (ignore-errors
                   (save-excursion
                     (evil-select-paren (car it) (cdr it)
                                        beg end type
                                        count inclusive))))
         (-min-by (-on #'> (lambda (x)
                             (abs (- (car x) (point) )))))
         (-take 2)))

(evil-define-text-object jds~evil-a-paren (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select a paren."
  :extend-selection nil 
  (jds~evil-paren-range count beg end type t))

(evil-define-text-object jds~evil-inner-paren (count &optional beg end type)
  "Select 'inner' paren."
    :extend-selection nil
        (jds~evil-paren-range count beg end type nil))

(define-key evil-inner-text-objects-map "d" #'jds~evil-inner-paren)
(define-key evil-outer-text-objects-map "d" #'jds~evil-a-paren)
```

---

- Both [`evil-a-paren` and  `evil-inner-paren`](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/a13a05f263dd54632d4509e7cfb2bb5df556d442/evil-commands.el#L1351) has `:extend-selection` nil.
- `evil-select-paren` moves point (or errs out).  The original code should use `save-excursion`
- `evil-up-block` is something you have added, and the corresponding branch is never taken.